# How do I solve the wave equation (WITH interaction)?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis, physics, mathematical-physics

I am unsure how to approach the added F(x,t) part of this partial differential equation.

$$\begin{cases} \partial_t^2u=\partial_x^2u+F(x,t),& x,t\in\mathbb{R}\,\\ u(x,0)=f(x)\\ \partial_tu(x,0)=g(x)\end{cases}$$

Comment: What did you try so far? You should update the question and show your attempts.

Comment: This is described in lots of books and lecture notes, just google “wave equation with source”.